# Is there a "quarter" equivalent for something divided in 9 pieces?

Tags: single-word-requests

Something is divided in four pieces. One piece is called a fourth or a quarter.

Something is divided in nine pieces. One is piece is called a ninth or a... What is the 'quarter' equivalent for something divided by nine?

Comment: There is no corresponding Latinate word for a ninth (that I've ever heard of, at least). If there were, it ought probably to be a _none_ or a _noner_, which would just be confusing.

Comment: Is there a corresponding word for a sixth? A seventh? An eighth? And why is there only one /t/ in *eighth?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers logically, an eighth is an octave.

Comment: @cde: I think I'd be inclined to say the relationship between **8** and **octave** is more akin to **3** and **triplet** (or **triad**). That's to say, an octave is a thing made up of 8 parts, not one of the 8 parts that make up a thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers wouldn't that be the difference between "**a** triplet" vs "triplets"?

Comment: @cde: Good point. Despite the fact that I actually posted *nonuplet* as the best of a bad bunch, when I wrote *triplet* I was actually thinking of the [*any group or combination of three*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/triplet) sense. But lets face it, I doubt you could get anyone to agree there are any contexts where *octave* and *octuplet* are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED has a definition for...

> ***ninth part**   n. each of the nine equal parts into which a thing may be divided; (also fig.) denoting a worthless or inadequate object or person, esp. in ninth part of a man.*

Other than that the only word I know is pretty specific - it only applies to each of a 9-baby birth...

> ***nonuplet** (defn 2.) Each of nine siblings resulting from a single pregnancy. Usu. in pl.*

Apparently [there's only one in the world](http://multiples.about.com/od/glossary/g/nonuplets.htm) (only two sets are known, and all the other babies died).

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm very late to this,  but I just did a crossword puzzle and the answer to the clue "many a pizza slice"  was "octant".

I find this definition via google:

1. an arc of a circle equal to one eighth of its circumference, or the area enclosed by such an arc with two radii of the circle. [Note:  this justifies the pizza slice answer.]
2. each of eight parts into which a space or solid body is divided by three planes that intersect (especially at right angles) at a single point.

H

Comment: 2^3 is 8. So cut it in half 3 times. Cut in half, stack up, cut in half, stack up, cut in half. Done. 8 identical pieces.

Comment: within seconds of posting I realized my question (how to divide a square cake into 8 equal parts) was easily answered.   Sorry to waste your time and thanks for a civil answer.

Comment: Yup. Isn't that how it goes?